# Fill image transparency just behind the mouse click

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

sorry for my bad English. 
I stuck into a problem that is I need to fill the image transparency with color not all the transparent image into color but where the mouse clicked.
Like I've an image this, [Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15AV4.gif)

And when I click on this area where the mouse cursor is it should be filled be color just behind the clicked area transparency. Like this [Should be filled like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKzkP.png)

Not like This [This should not be happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbV52.png)

Here is my code

```css
img:active{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<head>
<body>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/15AV4.gif">
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: It's quite bad practice to just display your desired result, can you share your current code to show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Shis is a case for SVG if ever I saw one